# FolderItemVerb.DoIt on Sticky Notes, or Snipping Tool Results in "cannot find the file specified"

Tags: vbscript, windows-7-x64, taskbar

Using VBScript to try and pin the "Sticky Notes" or "Snipping Tool" shortcuts to the taskbar, I get the error message "The system cannot find the file specified" when I invoke the `DoIt` method. However, if I pin any other shortcut (e.g. Caclulator, Notepad, Internet Explorer, MS Word) then the script works flawlessly.

```
Dim Application, FileSystem, Shell, PinnedFolder, PinnedItem, Verb, Shortcut
Set Application = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set FileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set Shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set Shortcut = FileSystem.GetFile(Shell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%ProgramData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Accessories\Sticky Notes.lnk"))
Set PinnedFolder = Application.Namespace(Shortcut.ParentFolder.Path)
Set PinnedItem = PinnedFolder.ParseName(Shortcut.Name)

For Each Verb In PinnedItem.Verbs
    If "Pin to Tas&kbar" = Verb.Name Then
        Verb.DoIt
    End If
Next
```

For example, if I change the path to `"%ProgramData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Accessories\Calculator.lnk"` then it does **not** throw the error, and the shortcut for Calculator is successfully pinned to the taskbar.

I can not find any reason why this only fails on those two shortcuts. I've tried recreating the shortcuts, moving them to a different location, and I've verified the shortcuts themselves work when double clicked. Does anyone know why this is happening or have any ideas I haven't tried?

**EDIT****

This has now been tested on two additional Windows 7 64bit PC's, and a Windows 7 32bit PC. All of which successfully pinned the Sticky Notes application. At least one of the Windows 7 64bit PC's as well as the 32bit PC has the same settings, software, and environment as the affected PC. Yet the problem still persists with the original PC.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works on my Windows7 x64 system.  However, try this (also works on mine).

```
Dim Application, FileSystem, Shell, PinnedFolder, PinnedItem, Verb, Shortcut
Set Application = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set FileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set Shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set Shortcut = FileSystem.GetFile(Shell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%windir%\system32\StikyNot.exe"))
Set PinnedFolder = Application.Namespace(Shortcut.ParentFolder.Path)
Set PinnedItem = PinnedFolder.ParseName(Shortcut.Name)

For Each Verb In PinnedItem.Verbs
    If "Pin to Tas&kbar" = Verb.Name Then
        Verb.DoIt
    End If
Next
```

If this doesn't work, try running it as the Administrator.

Comment: This does not work if I use `%windir%\system32\stikynot.exe`. Instead it throws the error on the `Set Shortcut...` line. Yet, I can copy and paste the same path into the Run dialog, and Sticky Notes launches with no problems. It works though if I use `%windir%\system32\notepad.exe`. It is looking like this is a machine specific problem.

Comment: Are you running (or have you tried) this as the administrator?

Comment: I have UAC set to "Never notify..." and I just tried this on another Windows 7 64bit machine with the same settings and it worked on it.

Comment: Permissions aren't only for UAC... Files, Folders, Reg Settings...  Lots of things could be at play here.  Testing under the full admin account rules out a lot of things.